# Micronaut http client exchange vs retrieve

Tags: http, client, micronaut

What are the differences between *exchange* and *retrieve* methods for [Micronaut HttpClient](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/http/client/HttpClient.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return type. See [HttpClient Javadoc](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/http/client/HttpClient.html)

`exchange` returns the [full http response](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/api/io/micronaut/http/HttpResponse.html)

Whereas `retrieve` returns the body of the http response.